# ClassNotFoundException: Proxylet.class

Tags: java

Estou tentando solicitar um talão pelo site da sefaz, mas aparece uma janela com a frase "`ClassNotFoundException: Proxylet.class`", e quando eu clico em informações, aparece isso que postei abaixo.

Vocês sabem o que é? Como resolve?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Proxylet.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Não confunda java com javascript. É a mesma coisa que confundir cachorro com cachorro-quente.

Comment: A sua applet foi compilada para rodar usando uma classe `Proxylet`, mas você está tentando rodar em um ambiente onde essa classe não está presente.

Comment: Você baixou essa aplicação onde?

Comment: E o que eu faço pra corrigir esse erro?

Comment: Foi no site da sefaz. Eu tô tentando pedir um talão, mas quando chega na pagina q eu marco o tipo de talão que quero, aparece isso.

Comment: Você provavelmente baixou uma aplicação incompleta, e provavelmente eles a publicaram incompleta. A julgar pelo nome da classe, que não tem pacote, é de se acreditar que não foi desenvolvida de forma profissional.

Comment: Eu conseguia emitir talões normalmente até semana pasada. Agora tá dando isso.

Comment: É o site da sefaz do estado da Bahia http://www.sefaz.ba.gov.br/
Mas sempre da algum tipo de erro e incompatibilidade com o JAVA. Aliais, a maioria dos sites do governo é assim.

Comment: Sem falar que applets já foram abandonadas por todos os navegadores há uns 2 anos já e eles ainda usam essa nhaca.

Comment: Se vc trabalhasse com contabilidade iria se deparar com esse tipo de "nhaca" todos os dias. Nem o java podemos atualizar pq tem sites que não funciona nos mais recentes.

Comment: Eu sei, eu trabalho num órgão público. Inclusive estou num projeto de modernizar uma porcaria dessas, mas aqui as coisas são difíceis.

Comment: Imagino o perrengue. Resumindo: Não há nada q eu possa fazer, né?

Comment: Acredito que não há muito o que fazer além de encher o saco da ouvidoria ou coisa assim. Eles colocaram no ar um programa que simplesmente não funciona por estar incompleto.

Comment: Preenche diretamente no site. Oh life difícil.

Comment: Mas, muito obrigada Victor, vc ajudou muito. Deus abençoe.

Comment: De nada. Boa sorte com isso.